# Match a substring in Pandas wit str.extract method

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a string looking like:

```
29818-218705-61709-2
```

I want to extract the second to last 5 digits number between the two dashes

```
61709
```

each string is contained in a pandas series:

I came up with:

```
df.id.str.extract(r'[.-]([0-9]{5})[.-]?')
```

but it extracts the first 5 digits group.

I can I match the one I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
[.-]([0-9]{5})[.-][0-9]+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UHzTOq/1)

**Details**:

- `[.-]` - a `.` or `-` separator
- `([0-9]{5})` - Group 1 capturing 5 digits
- `[.-]` - again a separator
- `[0-9]+` -1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

Thanks to the `$` anchor, the digit groups that are at the end are matched.

An alternative is to leverage backtracking with:

```
^.*[.-]([0-9]{5})[.-]
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/UHzTOq/3)

The `^.*` will match any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols from the start of the string, as many as possible, so the last `-|.`+`5 digits`+`-|.` are matched.

Comment: Glad it  worked for you. Please consider also upvoting the answer if it turned out helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `split`

```
df.id.str.split('-').str[-2]
```

---

***demo***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id=['29818-218705-61709-2'] * 1000)) 
df.id.str.split('-').str[-2].head()

0    61709
1    61709
2    61709
3    61709
4    61709
Name: id, dtype: object
```

Comment: My idea  was same ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> s = "29818-218705-61709-2 "
>>> s.split("-")[2]
'61709'
```